# Improve Query Function in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I've been using the following function:

```
=query(Sheet1!A2:D," select A, B, C where A matches '"&JOIN("|", A2:A)&"' and D matches 'yes'")
```

Is there anyway that I can make is so that every row that starts with a match will be added a comma separated list in which each column occupies one cell with no duplicates as shown in sheet3.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YDxIUnZzzYde9hcexPoDegv4HBuiUwk2wLKSXazu9hE/edit?usp=sharing

Sheet 2 has the function that I used and the result.

Comment: Sheet 3 is blank in your link

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what you want to do, but try this. In Sheet1 in E2 put this combining Col A and D:

```
=arrayFormula(A2:A & if(isBlank(D2:D),""," ") & D2:D)
```

In F2 combine Col C and D with this:

```
=arrayFormula(B2:B & if(isBlank(C2:C),"",",") & C2:C)
```

In G2 find the unique values from Col F with this:

```
=UNIQUE(E2:E)
```

In H2 put this and drag the formula down:

```
=join(",",query(E2:F,"select F where E contains '"& G2 &"'"))
```

Hide Cols E & F